# How can I pick-up a payload data in a nestd payload?

Tags: node.js, json, node-red

I have a couple of ingress payload like

```
{"topic":"homepi/dht11repub", "payload": 
     "{ \"timestamp\": \"2018-11-26T08:50:55Z\", 
     \"Temperature\": 17.0, 
     \"humidity\": 92.0 }",  
  "qos":0,"retain":false,"_msgid":"b7af75be.485088"}
```

I wanna pick the data in node-red function. I Have tried

```
var t =msg.payload
payload= t.payload
return msg
```

and

```
msg.payload[payload]
```

but it does not work.
Does anybody know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is the payload a single string and you want to return that?

Comment: I want transform it to a string to my chart dashboard,so the return payload must be a string

Comment: Is that the input payload or the whole message? because if it's just the whole message then `payload` doesn't have a `payload.payload` field.

Comment: I checked it again.Probably because my msg.payload value is caused by string, how do I need to convert the value of string to json format

Comment: here is whole message {"topic":"homepi/dht11repub","payload":"{ \"timestamp\": \"2018-11-26T15:00:41Z\",\"Temperature\": 17.0,\"humidity\": 92.0 }","qos":0,"retain":false,"_msgid":"7e4c6a91.81b394"},I found that the payload value was returned as a string, so the function behind could not be processed(Data is quoted "" formatted as string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the incoming message through the `JSON` node first to convert it to a JSON object.

If you still need it as a string afterwards you can pass it through another `JSON` node that will convert it back to a string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your payload is a json string.

Have you tried :

```
msg.payload = JSON.parse(msg.payload);
```

Or if you want to return only temperature as output :

```
const tmp  = JSON.parse(msg.payload);
return {payload: tmp.payload.Temperature};
```

Your syntax with msg.payload[payload] is incorrect, you should write msg.payload['payload'].

In Node-Red, the content is always returned in the payload property of the message msg. It's mandatory to respect this format.

[edit]
My mistake : your payload is a json string so I modify the code to reflect this.

Comment: Node-Red return error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u"

Comment: Two cases with that problem : your json string in not complete or it's a standard js object and it have been transformed in json format when you log it ?